# c# WPF remove ListBox Content ScrollBar Gap - Photo included

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

[image]

I have a custom scroll bar template that is set like this:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBar_New}"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

I am trying to move those buttons closer to the scroll bar and not sure if there is a setting I am missing someplace. Do I need to also modify the listbox control style? I am still new to WPF and not sure if there is something I am missing here. I have already tried `<Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>` to see if that that alters it, but it does not.

Style Used:

```
    <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                        <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="7" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!--ScrollBars-->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBar_Rounded" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFCC515" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="8" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="8" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Does your ScrollBar_New has a margin writed inside the template? can you please add the xaml of it?

Comment: @DanieleSartori added code for the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a little bit of testing i've come to my conclusion. In your style there are several things that affect the width of the scrollbar. To avoid to mess up the everything hardconding width

```
        <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                            <Border Margin="3" x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--ScrollBars-->
        <Style x:Key="ScrollBar_Rounded" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFCC515" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="Auto" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                                </Track.Thumb>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                                <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                                <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="8" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Shortly What i did was to :

- Change the setter of the Height Property for Rectangle 1 to auto (this cause to have horizonatal and vertical scrollbar to look the same)
- Set GridRoot Width to auto In the ScrollBar_Rounded style (this cause the scrollbar to get all the available space)
- Use a margin in the Rectangle1 to the desired space (this will help you to decide how much space should be displayed between your scrollbars and the content of the listbox)

Comment: Very cool. I was messing with the Margin, but I guess I did not know I needed to set those other properties to auto. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but in my test the scrollbar take all the space available. If you change the margin you can create the amount of space desired.

Comment: @danielsartori Sorry, I deleted the comment since I figured it out! I was able to tweak the margin to get it the way I wanted it. At some point I am going to look into how I can reduce the the space the listbox control assigns to a scroll bar. I am going to assume I will have to make a custom style for it.